# How to grab a form input in HTML using bash?

Tags: php, html, bash

I am making a little project that grabs the HTML input from a local hosted website and then parses it through bash to open certain amount tabs using Bash.

Pseudo code:

```
<Input>50<Input> --> Bash grab HTML<Input>50<Input> --> loop 50: chrome.exe google.com
```

Code of my HTML input field:

```
<label class="tabAmount">Tab Amount: <input class="tabCount" type="number" name="tabSize" size="4" min="1" max="9999"></label>
```

So, my main problem is that I need a Bash command to search for the HTML input and then parse it through the script to open the tabs.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: There isn't really a clear or direct connection between bash and HTML that's loaded into a browser as a webpage... so the question you're asking doesn't really make sense. Also, I'm afraid that's not pseudocode.

Comment: If it is locally hosted, why do you need to parse it?
Also, if the web page is already loaded, you can easily open multiple tabs in the browser using javascript's `window.open(...)` or `link.click()` mechanisms. No need for `bash` parsing.

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: You cannot use Javascript because chrome limits the amount of tabs you can open at a time. It's their rules. So I have to use a webpage that takes my inputs then runs a local bash script with a loop to get around their rules. This is tagged PHP because HTML/Javascript cannot communicate with Bash so I parse my HTML to PHP then to Bash to run my loop that opens tabs. Honestly don't know why I get downvotes for this? This is a perfectly fine question.

Answer (score 1):

This is my html code:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/grab_html_input.sh">
  Enter Number:<br>
  <input type="number" name="number"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my bash script:

```
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS='=&'
parm=($QUERY_STRING)
IFS=$saveIFS

number=${parm[1]}

while (( number > 0 ))
do
  <command line command goes here>
done
```

I don't know the command to open new tab but this is the foundation that I've used to pass HTML input into a bash script.